# If a function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for all $x \in D$, does that imply the domain is an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

## Context

I am working through Advanced Calculus, Fitzpatrick. Fitzpatrick uses a different definition of *continuous* than most other books, such as Rudin.

> A function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *continuous at the point* $x_{0}$ in $D$ provided that whenever $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $x_0$, the image sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $f(x_0)$. The function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *continuous* provided that it is continuous at every point in $D$.

My question is, if a function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for all $x \in D$, does that imply the domain $D$ is an interval? Why?

## Attempt

Rough sketch of a proof idea I had, trying a proof by contradiction. This is not rigorous, just trying to sketch my thoughts

Assume $D$ is an interval $[a, b]$. Then "remove" some $x \in [a, b]$, so $f$ is not defined on $x$.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be some sequence in $[a, b]$. Then since it is bounded, by the sequential compactness theorem, there is some subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $x$. Then since $f$ is continuous, the image $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$ converges to $f(x)$. But $f$ is not defined on $x$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $D$ is an interval.

I doubt this is right, but it's where I'm at after reading a few similar proofs in the book (Extreme Value Theorem, Intermediate Value Theorem). Would be helpful if any explanations use the Fitzpatrick definition of continuity.

Comment: @Oreomair I think you have it backwards. The image of any interval under a continuous function is an inverval. All you know for the preimage is that the preimage of any open set is open.

Comment: Yes, you know what I'm wrong, excuse me.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $x_k$ converges to $x$. If $x \not \in D$ then $x_k$ does *not* converge to a point in $D$ so the definition of continuous doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition we are discussing continuity at an $x_0\in D$, so we consider sequences in $D$ converging to $x_0$. If a point is not in $D$, i.e., if $f$ is not defined at a point, then it is meaningless to ask about the continuity of $f$ at that point.

Secondly, it is not true that *any* sequence in $[a, b]\setminus \{x\}$ has a subsequence converging to $x$, it could converge to other points as well.

Lastly, it doesn't mean that $D$ should be an interval, for example the identity function is continuous on $(0, 1)\cup (2, 3]\cup\{4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. Take $D=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ and let $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in D$.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean $D = [0, 2]$?

Comment: @Watercrystal haha yes good catch. Updated

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, in fact one can show e.g. that any function $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. This would be because any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converging to some $x \in \mathbb N$ will already have $a_m = x$ for all $m$ larger than some finite threshold and hence, $(f(a_n))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ must converge to $f(x)$, making $f$ continuous.